Prove $(x_1 +x_2 +...+x_i +...+x_n)^2 \ge n(x_1x_2 +x_2x_3 +...+x_ix_{i+1} +...+x_nx_1)$
Determine all positive integers $n \ge 2$ such that for all POSITIVE real number $x_1, x_2,..., x_n$ the following inequality holds:
$$(x_1 +x_2 +...+x_i +...+x_n)^2 \ge n(x_1x_2 +x_2x_3 +...+x_ix_{i+1} +...+x_nx_1)$$
I am very aware VERY similar problems have already been solved, for example, the All Soviet Union MO 1973, and the problem I found here find all $n\ge 2$ so that $(x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_n)^2 \ge n(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+\cdots + x_nx_1)\,\forall x_1,\cdots, x_n\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$.
The problem is these solutions all work for non-negative numbers, I already know how to solve it (if you're interested in the solution, click the link above), but I struggle to find the solution for positive reals. If anyone knows the solution or the link to the solution, it would be much appreciated, I spent four days trying to find the solution. Please note that this question is not a duplicate, as far as I know, because all the solutions that I found are for non-negative reals...
EDIT: If this question turns out to be a duplicate, and the solution is correct, I will probably delete this question if you guys ask me to. Or maybe I will leave it, to be accessible to everyone... Please feel free to let me know.

Positive real numbers are non-negative.

Yes, but $0$ is included in non-negative numbers. $0$ is not a positive number.

If the inequality holds for all positive numbers then a simple continuity argument shows that it holds for all nonnegative numbers as well.

All the solutions I found use $0$ for the equality case, but in this "version" it is not allowed.

@MartinR yes, but in this case it is the other way around. I know it holds for non-negative numbers, but that doesn't mean it holds for all positive, if that's what you meant to say.

I think I solved it in positive reals. Here is the solution:
We will prove that for all $n > 4$, the statement does not hold.
First, for $n \le 4$ we have:
$n=2$
\begin{align*}
(x_1 + x_2)^2 &\ge 2(x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_1) \\
x_1^2 + 2x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 &\ge 4x_1 x_2 \\
x_1^2 + x_2^2 &\ge 2x_1 x_2
\end{align*}
which obviously holds due to the AM-GM inequality.
$n=3$
\begin{align*}
(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^2 &\ge 3(x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 + x_3 x_1) \\
x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + 2x_1 x_2 + 2x_2 x_3 + 2x_3 x_1 &\ge 3(x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 + x_3 x_1) \\
x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 &\ge x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 + x_3 x_1
\end{align*}
which holds by the rearrangement inequality or we can multiply everything by 2 and get
$$(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (x_2 - x_3)^2 + (x_3 - x_1)^2 \ge 0$$
which obviously holds.
$n=4$
Without loss of generality, assume that $x_1$ is the smallest number and $x_4$ is the largest number among them. We have:
\begin{align*}
(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4)^2 &\ge 4(x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 + x_3 x_4 + x_4 x_1) \\
&\ldots \\
x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 + 2x_1 x_3 + 2x_2 x_4 &\ge 2x_1 x_2 + 2x_2 x_3 + 2x_3 x_4 + 2x_4 x_1 \\
2x_1 x_3 + 2x_2 x_4 &\stackrel{\text{AM-GM}}{\ge} 2x_2 x_3 + 2x_1 x_4 \\
\Leftrightarrow (x_2 - x_1)(x_4 - x_3) &\ge 0
\end{align*}
which obviously holds due to our assumption.
Now we will prove that we can always find numbers for $n > 4$ for which the statement does not hold. Let $x_1 = x_2 = 1$ and $x_i = x > 0$ for each $n \ge i \ge 3$. The inequality "opposite" to the given inequality is:
$$(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_i + \cdots + x_n)^2 < n(x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 + \cdots + x_i x_{i+1} + \cdots + x_n x_1)$$
and substituting the previously mentioned values, we have
\begin{align*}
(1 + 1 + (n - 2)x)^2 &< n(1 + 2x + (n - 3)x^2) \\
(2 + nx - 2x)^2 &< n(1 + 2x + nx^2 - 3x^2) \\
4 + n^2 x^2 + 4x^2 + 4nx - 8x - 4nx^2 &< n + 2xn + n^2 x^2 - 3nx^2 \\
4 + 4x^2 - 8x - nx^2 + 2nx &< n \\
4 + 4x^2 - 8x - nx^2 + 2nx - n &< 0 \\
4(1 - 2x + x^2) - n(x^2 - 2x + 1) &< 0 \\
(4 - n)(x - 1)^2 &< 0
\end{align*}
Since $4 - n < 0$ and $(x - 1)^2 > 0$ for $x \neq 1$, the last inequality holds. Thus, we have found numbers for which the opposite of the statement holds, i.e., for which the statement does not hold. (These numbers are $x_1 = x_2 = 1$ and $x_i = x > 0, x \neq 1$ for each $n \ge i \ge 3$).
Therefore, we have proven that the statement holds for arbitrary numbers only for
$$n \in \{2, 3, 4\}$$

It is kind of underwhelming that there are infinite solutions, or should I say "anti-solutions". I thought the problem would have more specific anti-solutions, but it is what it is.

Also, a big thank you to @ameg, your comment gave me the idea of the solution!

The positive and nonnegative conditions are the same:
Suppose that the statement is true for all non-negative numbers, then since the positive numbers are a subset of the non-negative numbers, the statement is also true for the positive numbers.
On the other hand, suppose that the statement is not true for non-negative numbers.  Then there is some $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ where the statement fails.  If all $x_i$ are positive, then the statement is not true for positive numbers.  Therefore, we are left to consider the case where some of the $x_i$'s are zero.  In this case,
$$
(x_1+\dots+x_n)^n<n(x_1x_2+\dots+x_nx_1).
$$
Let
$$
\delta = n(x_1x_2+\dots+x_nx_1)-(x_1+\dots+x_n)^n.
$$
By adding a very small $\varepsilon$ to each $x_i$, you can make it so that
$$
((x_1+\varepsilon)+\dots+(x_n+\varepsilon))^n<(x_1+\dots+x_n)^n+\delta.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
n(x_1x_2+\dots+x_nx_1)\leq n((x_1+\varepsilon)(x_2+\varepsilon)+\dots+(x_n+\varepsilon)(x_1+\varepsilon)).
$$
Putting this all together, we have that
\begin{align*}
((x_1+\varepsilon)+\dots+(x_n+\varepsilon))^n&<(x_1+\dots+x_n)^n+\delta\\
&=n(x_1x_2+\dots+x_nx_1)\\
&\leq n((x_1+\varepsilon)(x_2+\varepsilon)+\dots+(x_n+\varepsilon)(x_1+\varepsilon)).
\end{align*}
Since each $x_i+\varepsilon$ is positive, this shows that the statement also fails when the $x_i$'s are positive.
